# Can't edit or make new Mosaico Template

Tags: mosaico

When I try to edit a Mosaico template in FireFox or in Chrome, it acts as if I am trying to print a "Welcome to your Home Dashboard" page. The URL looks like this:
https://yobc.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/mosaico/editor&snippet=2&ip-geo-block-auth-nonce=5234197d0a#ivfia57 .
If I cancel that "print," I get a Configure Your Dashboard message. The URL looks like this:
https://yobc.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/mosaico/editor&snippet=2&ip-geo-block-auth-nonce=5234197d0a#ivfia57

It appears that this plugin is up-to-date, and we have used it for some time. Updated CiviCrm last week with the security update.

Pictures attached.

[image: What I see when I click Edit next to a template]

[image: After closing the "print" screen]

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to clean CiviCRM cache and do a menu rebuild?  You can do this by navigating to CiviCRM >> Administer >> System Settings >> Cleanup Caches and Update paths. Once you on the page click on Cleanup cache button.

[image]

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: So can my comment be marked as answered? It will be useful for people to know.